# No numbers on default keyboard

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, keyboard, sony-xperia-arc

Just bought a SE Xperia Arc S phone and it's keyboard does not have numbers or symbols like $,@ on the keys. When I press and hold "r" for example it prints a weird "ṛ" character instead of the number 4.
Is there a way to have a keyboard like in Galaxy S, with symbols and numbers (and still have swype)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what input methods your device has by following the screen shots-

[image: Step 1]  [image: Step 2] [image: Step 3]

You should be able to see all installed keyboards by following the guide, and select the one which suits you. Or if you don't have much options there, install a new keyboard input method from Market or install Swype beta by registering [here](http://beta.swype.com/).