# Macedonian keyboard for Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: keyboard, localization

I'm from Macedonia and I'm using Samsung Galaxy Ace and I was wondering if there is any way I can install Macedonian keyboard so I can type in my mother language?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this should work for you - [**Macedonian Keyboard App Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mk.com.hae.macedoniankeyboard)

Install and change input method when typing to use this keyboard. (To change input method, you can follow this guide - [Android Stack Exchange - Change Input Method](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/no-numbers-on-default-keyboard/22201#22201))

> After changing keyboard, select **'123'** near space button and then
>   select **'MKD'** at same place to get the Macedonian Keyboard.

You can also try other popular Keyboard apps if they have Macedonian support, unfortunately [Swype](http://beta.swype.com/android/supported/) doesn't have it.

[image: Step 1] [image: Step 2]

Comment: Yes! I have Macedonian keyboard now and I'm so happy about it. :) I installed the application from the store. Thanks a lot for the help Sameer, I thought it was impossible to have it.